# need to write an xslt to transform xml to csv with specific data

Tags: xml, csv, xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm trying to write an xslt which creates a csv from an xml. I need to create a header field mapping such that header matches the data.
Here is an example xml

```
  <headerFieldsMap>
    <BusinessUnit>Business Unit Code</BusinessUnit>
    <CompanyName>Business Unit Desct</CompanyName>
    <DeptDescr>Department Description</DeptDescr>
    <DeptId>Department</DeptId>
    <DescrShort>Posting Job Title</DescrShort>
    <Description>Working Position Description</Description>
    <JobFamily>Category</JobFamily>
    <PositionNbr>Position-Nbr</PositionNbr>
    <StdHoursFreq>Standard hours Frequency</StdHoursFreq>
    <TotalWorkingHours>Standard Hours</TotalWorkingHours>
  </headerFieldsMap>
  <psPositions>
    <position>
      <LocationPostal>06511</LocationPostal>
      <ConfidentialFlag>N</ConfidentialFlag>
      <DeptDescr>New Haven EMU Shop</DeptDescr>
      <Description>Carman E Rate</Description>
      <RegTemp>R</RegTemp>
      <SalAdminPlan>TWUR</SalAdminPlan>
      <JobCodeSetid>SHARE</JobCodeSetid>
      <LocationCountry>US</LocationCountry>
      <Remote>N</Remote>
      <Step>0</Step>
      <SalaryRangeTo>0</SalaryRangeTo>
      <PositionNbr>01000333</PositionNbr>
      <SalaryRangeFrom>0</SalaryRangeFrom>
      <EffStatus>A</EffStatus>
      <FullPartTime>F</FullPartTime>
      <PositionStatus>Approved</PositionStatus>
      <LocationSetId>SHARE</LocationSetId>
      <CompanyName>Metro-North Railroad</CompanyName>
      <RemainingHeadCount>0</RemainingHeadCount>
      <PayFrequency>H</PayFrequency>
      <JobCode>26448E</JobCode>
      <RegRegion>USA</RegRegion>
      <Shift>2</Shift>
      <ReportsToPos>01000474</ReportsToPos>
      <DeptIdSetId>MNCRR</DeptIdSetId>
      <TotalWorkingHours>40</TotalWorkingHours>
      <DescrShort>Carman E R</DescrShort>
      <StdHoursFreq>W</StdHoursFreq>
      <LocationCode>NEW HAVEN</LocationCode>
      <Effdt>2023-02-21</Effdt>
      <LocationDescr>98 Union Street</LocationDescr>
      <LocationCity>New Haven</LocationCity>
      <Grade>004</Grade>
      <JobFamily>Transportation Operations</JobFamily>
      <DeptId>44302</DeptId>
      <LastUpdDtTm>2023-02-21T19:12:05Z</LastUpdDtTm>
      <LocationRegion>CT</LocationRegion>
      <ReportsToEmail>Burns@mnr.org</ReportsToEmail>
      <PayCurrency>USD</PayCurrency>
      <MaxHeadCount>1</MaxHeadCount>
      <BusinessUnit>MNCRR</BusinessUnit>
      <JobFamilyCode>TRNOPS</JobFamilyCode>
      <CompanyCode>MNR</CompanyCode>
      <CurrHeadCount>1</CurrHeadCount>
    </position>
 </psPositions>
</root>
```

The csv or the output should look like this

```
Business Unit Code,Business Unit Desct,Department Description,Department,Posting Job Title,Working Position Description,Category,Position-Nbr,Standard hours Frequency,Standard Hours
MNCRR,Metro-North Railroad,New Haven EMU Shop,44302,Carman E R,Carman E Rate,Transportation Operations,01000333,W,40
MTAHQ,MTA Headquarters,Division of Management /Budget,400300,SR FINANCI,Sr Financial Analyst - Budgets,Finance/Accounting,01055644,W,37.5
```

Note that the data only has the values for the fields which are mentioned in the  field. The fields in the  may vary, there could only be 2 fields that come in, the data should show up accordingly.

Current xslt i have is this

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

  <xsl:variable name="delimiter" select="','"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <!-- Header row -->
    <xsl:for-each select="root/headerFieldsMap/*">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
        <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>

    <!-- Data rows -->
    <xsl:for-each select="root/psPositions/position">
      <xsl:for-each select="*">
        <xsl:variable name="fieldName" select="name()"/>
        <xsl:variable name="fieldValue" select="."/>

        <!-- If the field value is StdHoursFreq and it's equal to "W", replace it with "Weekly" -->
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="$fieldName = 'StdHoursFreq' and $fieldValue = 'W'">
            <xsl:text>Weekly</xsl:text>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$fieldValue"/>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>

        <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
          <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
      <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But this one prints out all the data from the xml. I only need the data that is mentioned in the header.
XSLT standards: 1.0

The above xslt generates the output that looks like the one below. It shouldn't have data for the fields that are not in the header, like "Burns@mnr.org" shouldn't be there because "ReportsToEmail" isn't there in the header.

```
Business Unit Code,Business Unit Desct,Department Description,Department,Posting Job Title,Working Position Description,Category,Position-Nbr,Standard hours Frequency,Standard Hours
06511,N,New Haven EMU Shop,Carman E Rate,R,TWUR,SHARE,US,N,0,0,01000333,0,A,F,Approved,SHARE,Metro-North Railroad,0,H,26448E,USA,2,01000474,MNCRR,40,Carman E R,Weekly,NEW HAVEN,2023-02-21,98 Union Street,New Haven,004,Transportation Operations,44302,2023-02-21T19:12:05Z,CT,Burns@mnr.org,USD,1,MNCRR,TRNOPS,MNR,1
10004,Y,Division of Management /Budget,Sr Financial Analyst - Budgets,R,HAY0,SHARE,US,N,0,0,01055644,0,A,F,Approved,SHARE,MTA Headquarters,1,B,1287,USA,1,01005823,MTAHQ,37.5,SR FINANCI,Weekly,2 BROADWAY,2023-02-21,2 Broadway,New York,438,Finance/Accounting,400300,2023-02-21T12:57:45Z,NY,USD,1,MTAHQ,FINANC,MTA,0
```

Comment: While asking an XSLT question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Input XML.
(2) Your logic, and XSLT that tries to implement it.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample XML in the #1 above.
(4) XSLT processor and its conformance with the XSLT standards: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, or 4.0.

Comment: Please provide all ##1-4

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky I have edited the question to provide more information. Is this enough?

Comment: Your XML file header's columns sequential order doesn't match the desired output.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky the sequence should be how it is in <headerFieldsMap>. Sorry it doesn't match with the csv. the csv was generated by java code

Comment: Again, please provide all ##1-4, and explain what is currently working and what is not

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky I have updated and added more info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following XSLT.

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

    <xsl:variable name="delimiter" select="','"/>

    <xsl:template match="/root">
        <!-- Header row -->
        <xsl:for-each select="headerFieldsMap/*">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
                <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>

        <!-- Data rows -->
        <xsl:for-each select="psPositions/position">
            <xsl:variable name="row" select="."/>
            <xsl:for-each select="/root/headerFieldsMap/*">
                <xsl:variable name="fieldName" select="local-name()"/>
                <xsl:variable name="fieldValue" select="."/>

                <!-- If the field value is StdHoursFreq and it's equal to "W", replace it with "Weekly" -->
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="$row/*[local-name()=$fieldName] = 'W' and $row/*[local-name()='StdHoursFreq']">
                        <xsl:text>Weekly</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="$fieldName = 'DescrShort'">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$row/*[local-name()='LocationPostal']"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$row/*[local-name()=$fieldName]"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>

                <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: How can i map "Posting Job Title" to other header field if required? Like "Posting Job Title" to another field lets say "JobFamily"

Comment: Did you have a chance to give it a shot?

Comment: This works as expected. Thank you! Just one more thing. The field in <headerFieldsMap> are fixed, like <BusinessUnit>, <CompanyName>, <DeptDescr>etc. The values coming in them may change. Right now, "Posting Job Title" is pointing to <DescrShort>, what if i have to make it point to <Description> at some point. how will i do it?

Comment: I added one new clause to the `<xsl:choose>`. Just substitute **WhateverYouNeed** to **Description**. You can use such technique to handle exceptions. As many as you have them.

Comment: it doesn't work if i put "LocationPostal" in place of "WhateverYouNeed". It doesn't fetch the value of LocationPostal

Comment: It is working for me. Check the XSLT again, I replaced it directly in the answer.

Comment: yes, it is working. Thanks so much this solves everything!

Comment: Glad to hear that the proposed solution is working for you.

Answer (score 1):

> I only need the data that is mentioned in the header

Try it along the lines of:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:key name="row-data" match="position/*" use="concat(name(), generate-id(..))" />

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:variable name="cols" select="headerFieldsMap/*"/>
    <!-- header row-->
    <xsl:for-each select="$cols">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">,</xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    <!-- data rows-->
    <xsl:for-each select="psPositions/position">
        <xsl:variable name="row-id" select="generate-id()"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="$cols">
            <xsl:value-of select="key('row-data', concat(name(), $row-id))"/>
            <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">,</xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that the result obtained from your input XML is very different from what you show. Nevertheless, the stylesheet conforms to the logic presented in your question (at least the way I understood it).

---

To change `W` to `Weekly`, you could do:

```
        <xsl:for-each select="$cols">
            <xsl:variable name="value" select="key('row-data', concat(name(), $row-id))" />
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="name() = 'StdHoursFreq' and $value = 'W'">Weekly</xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$value"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
            <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">,</xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: This looks good. How can i map "Posting Job Title" to other header field if required? Also, I want to add a condition where if the value of "StdHoursFreq" comes as "W", it shoud print "Weekly"

Comment: I am afraid I don't understand what you mean by "map". Re the other part, see the addition to my answer. In general, once you understand how this works, you should be able to make the necessary adjustments yourself.

Comment: The field in <headerFieldsMap> are fixed, like <BusinessUnit>, <CompanyName>, <DeptDescr>etc. The values coming in them may change. Right now, "Posting Job Title" is pointing to <DescrShort>, what if i have to make it point to <Description> at some point. how will i do it?

Comment: If you want data from the `Description` element in `position` then you can get it using `key('row-data', concat('Description', $row-id))`. But your `headerFieldsMap` already has a  `Description` element, so this makes no sense.

Comment: Note that what ties the two sections together are the element names, not the values in  the header.  "Posting Job Title" is NOT pointing to <DescrShort>. The name `DescrShort` is pointing to the label "Posting Job Title" in header and to the corresponding values in data rows. If that's not the logic you need to apply, then we need to start over. Or at least add a preliminary stage of remapping the header names to values.

Comment: how do we add a preliminary stage of remapping the header names to values? Because for very few cases i might have to change the value at some point. How can we map header in the beginning?  That would be really helpful

Comment: If there's only one or two exceptions, you could implement them in a similar way to the W => Weekly exception, only on the other side of the key. Otherwise I would add a "dictionary" that states the rules for some (or all) headings. At this point am not sure what exactly those rules are - and I think this exceeds the scope of your question here (which I chose to answer only after you added the statement I quoted at the top of my answer). If that statement is no longer true, then I suggest you post a new question ad explain in detail the logic you want to implement.