# Transforming XML to CSV with a filter

Tags: xml, csv, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have an xml that and an XSLT that converts the xml to a csv. Here headerFieldsMap is the header of csv and psPositions is the data. XML version is 1.0
I need to make changes so the xslt so that the header named PositionNbr if exist should always be the first column of csv. Currently "Business Unit Code" is coming as the first column in the CSV, but I want "Position-Nbr" to be the first column if it exist in the < headerFieldsMap>.
This is the xml

```
 <root>
 <headerFieldsMap>
    <BusinessUnit>Business Unit Code</BusinessUnit>
    <CompanyName>Business Unit Desct</CompanyName>
    <DeptDescr>Department Description</DeptDescr>
    <DeptId>Department</DeptId>
    <DescrShort>Posting Job Title</DescrShort>
    <Description>Working Position Description</Description>
    <JobFamily>Category</JobFamily>
    <PositionNbr>Position-Nbr</PositionNbr>
    <StdHoursFreq>Standard hours Frequency</StdHoursFreq>
    <TotalWorkingHours>Standard Hours</TotalWorkingHours>
  </headerFieldsMap>
  <psPositions>
    <position>
      <LocationPostal>06511</LocationPostal>
      <ConfidentialFlag>N</ConfidentialFlag>
      <DeptDescr>New Haven EMU Shop</DeptDescr>
      <Description>Carman E Rate</Description>
      <RegTemp>R</RegTemp>
      <SalAdminPlan>TWUR</SalAdminPlan>
      <JobCodeSetid>SHARE</JobCodeSetid>
      <LocationCountry>US</LocationCountry>
      <Remote>N</Remote>
      <Step>0</Step>
      <SalaryRangeTo>0</SalaryRangeTo>
      <PositionNbr>01000333</PositionNbr>
      <SalaryRangeFrom>0</SalaryRangeFrom>
      <EffStatus>A</EffStatus>
      <FullPartTime>F</FullPartTime>
      <PositionStatus>Approved</PositionStatus>
      <LocationSetId>SHARE</LocationSetId>
      <CompanyName>Metro-North Railroad</CompanyName>
      <RemainingHeadCount>0</RemainingHeadCount>
      <PayFrequency>H</PayFrequency>
      <JobCode>26448E</JobCode>
      <RegRegion>USA</RegRegion>
      <Shift>2</Shift>
      <ReportsToPos>01000474</ReportsToPos>
      <DeptIdSetId>MNCRR</DeptIdSetId>
      <TotalWorkingHours>40</TotalWorkingHours>
      <DescrShort>Carman E R</DescrShort>
      <StdHoursFreq>W</StdHoursFreq>
      <LocationCode>NEW HAVEN</LocationCode>
      <Effdt>2023-02-21</Effdt>
      <LocationDescr>98 Union Street</LocationDescr>
      <LocationCity>New Haven</LocationCity>
      <Grade>004</Grade>
      <JobFamily>Transportation Operations</JobFamily>
      <DeptId>44302</DeptId>
      <LastUpdDtTm>2023-02-21T19:12:05Z</LastUpdDtTm>
      <LocationRegion>CT</LocationRegion>
      <ReportsToEmail>Burns@mnr.org</ReportsToEmail>
      <PayCurrency>USD</PayCurrency>
      <MaxHeadCount>1</MaxHeadCount>
      <BusinessUnit>MNCRR</BusinessUnit>
      <JobFamilyCode>TRNOPS</JobFamilyCode>
      <CompanyCode>MNR</CompanyCode>
      <CurrHeadCount>1</CurrHeadCount>
    </position>
 </psPositions>
</root>
```

This is the xslt

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
                xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xmlns:req="http://peoplesoft.com/requestResponse"
                xmlns:csl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

    <xsl:variable name="delimiter" select="','"/>

    <xsl:template match="/root">
        <!-- Header row -->
        <xsl:for-each select="headerFieldsMap/*">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
                <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>

        <!-- Data rows -->
         <xsl:for-each select="psPositions/position">
            <xsl:variable name="row" select="."/>
            <xsl:for-each select="/root/headerFieldsMap/*">
                <xsl:variable name="fieldName" select="local-name()"/>
                <xsl:variable name="fieldValue" select="."/>

                <!-- If the field value is StdHoursFreq and it's equal to "W", replace it with "Weekly" -->
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="$row/*[local-name()=$fieldName] = 'W' and $fieldName = 'StdHoursFreq'">
                        <xsl:text>Weekly</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="$row/*[local-name()=$fieldName] = 'B' and $fieldName = 'StdHoursFreq'">
                        <xsl:text>Bi-Weekly</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="$row/*[local-name()=$fieldName] = 'M' and $fieldName = 'StdHoursFreq'">
                        <xsl:text>Monthly</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="$fieldName = 'DescrShort'">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$row/*[local-name()='Description']"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$row/*[local-name()=$fieldName]"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>

                <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: So you need the ` Business Unit Code` field to be the first column? I have to say that for any real CSV parser, as long as there is a header, it doesn't matter where a field is located.

Comment: No i need "Position-Nbr" as the first column. Can it be done with minimum code change?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way you could look at it:

**XSLT 1.0 (+EXSLT node-set() function)**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:variable name="cols-rtf">
        <xsl:for-each select="headerFieldsMap/*">
            <xsl:sort select="number(name()='PositionNbr')" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="cols" select="exsl:node-set($cols-rtf)/*"/>
    <!-- header row-->
    <xsl:for-each select="$cols">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">,</xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    <!-- data rows-->
    <xsl:for-each select="psPositions/position">
        <xsl:variable name="row" select="."/>
        <xsl:for-each select="$cols">
            <xsl:value-of select="$row/*[name()=name(current())]"/>
            <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">,</xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

A more efficient way would be to use a [**key**](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116/#key) to lookup the row's data as shown in [my answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75598775/3016153). But since here the source of column names is an independent variable, you would need to switch the context back to the XML source before calling the key.

P.S. I have ignored the `xsl:choose` part of your XSLT which has nothing to do with the question.